# Is it possible to express the type of balanced untagged binary trees on the calculus of constructions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, dependent-type, morte

I'm trying to explore and understand the realms of the calculus of constructions through the project [Morte](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/09/morte-intermediate-language-for-super.html). I know one could represent such datatype in Agda, but it is not obvious to me how to represent it in such a minimalist environment. How could that be done? I mean this datatype, in Idris:

```
data Tree : Nat -> Type -> Type where
    Leaf : a -> Tree Z a
    (::) : Tree k a -> Tree k a -> Tree (S k) a
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not asking for a proper implementation but rather a high-level overview of how it could be done!

Comment: Just so it's clear what a 'balanced untagged binary tree' is, could you provide a reference implementation in Agda or Haskell?

Comment: It's not a trivial thing to define balanced trees even with inductive types, why would you want to mess with Church encoding?

Comment: @user2407038 woops, I am sorry. Forgot the most important bit. I updated the question. I also think this isn't called what I called it. I'm not sure how it is called.

Comment: Your `Tree` is a degenerate case called "perfectly balanced tree". See [here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/AVL.agda) for the regular balanced trees.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the details of Morte, but I have some clues about what's possible in typed lambda-calculi more broadly.

If `Nat` is defined impredicatively, it might be possible to define these trees by iteration.

```
Nat : *
Nat = (x : *) -> (x -> x) -> x -> x
Pair : * -> * -> *
Pair x y = (z : *) -> (x -> y -> z) -> z
Tree : * -> Nat -> *
Tree a n = n * (\ t -> Pair t t) a
```

Of course, to get away with that, I need a *large* elimination. Here, I've casually just taken `* : *`, but that's not safe in general. Inductive definitions admit large eliminations unproblematically: impredicatively encoded datatypes, not so.

But, above, I exploit the fact that the indexing structure of the trees happens to be compatible with that of the `Nat`s which index them, and there is no reason why that should be the case in general. Indices vary in all sorts of wacky ways: it's only those that characterize some sort of "size" that get smaller as we go inward.

Indexed structures do admit a Church encoded presentation. It's just that instead of iterating over a set, we iterate over an indexed set. Here's one way to express it.

```
Tree : * -> Nat -> *
Tree a n = (x : Nat -> *) ->
           (a -> x Z) ->
           ((n : Nat) -> x n -> x n -> x (S n)) ->
           x n
```

It's easy to write some things like

```
leftmost : (a : *) -> (n : Nat) -> Tree a n -> a
leftmost a n t = t (\ _ -> a) (\ a -> a) (\ _ l _ -> l)
```

but

```
leftChild : (a : *) -> (n : Nat) -> Tree a (S n) -> Tree a n
```

is a taller order, requiring some way to inspect or constrain numbers. That's why GHC Haskell has all this stuff about equality, `~`.

Answer (score 3):

What I have seen of Morte, everything is encoded using Church encoding. E.g. list example from post you linked:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
```

is encoded as

```
type List a = forall x . (a -> x -> x) -> x -> x
```

---

The first example of dependent typing is length-indexed lists aka vectors:

```
data Vec a (n :: Nat) where
  VNil :: forall a. Vec a 0
  VCons :: forall a (n :: Nat). a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

What is the Church encoding of such beast? I don't know which thinking heuristic works better for you,
you have to discover it yourself.

My way of thinking: Vector is very different from list. It's more of n-ary homogeous *tuple*. Few example encodings:

```
type Singleton a  = forall x. (a -> x) -> x            -- Vec a 1
type Pair a       = forall x. (a -> a -> x) -> x       -- Vec a 2
type Triple a     = forall x. (a -> a -> a -> x) -> x  -- Vec a 3
```

The pattern is obvious. What we need is a function from natural numbers to that family of types:

```
nTupleType a 0 x  = x
nTupleType a 1 x  = a -> x         = a -> nTupleType a 0 x
nTupleType a 2 x  = a -> (a -> x)  = a -> nTupleType a 1 x
nTupleType a n x  = ... -- General equation is left as an exercise
```

Given this, we can encode `Vec`:

```
type Vec a n = forall x. nTupleType a n x -> x

vnil = \x -> x
vcons (a : *) (n : Nat) (h : a) (t : Vec a n) = \x f -> t x (f h) -- I'm not sure if I got this right
```

---

Using similar method you can encode other indexed data structures. In the case of original question: complete balanced tree, the encoding will look very very similar, the `nTupleType` have to be changed from linear to expontential `(0,1,2,3, ...)` to `(1, 2, 4, 8, ...)`.

It's worth noticing, that actual shape of the tree will be quite hidden in Morte: `Tree a n ~ Vec a (exp2 n)`. OTOH that's the point of Morte. I guess.